# Pandas select rows in DataFrameGroupBy bases on hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (called *df*):

```
   user_id  product_id  probReorder
0        1         196          1.0
1        1       10258          0.9
2        1       10326          0.1
3        1       12427          1.0
4        1       13032          0.3
...
```

For each *user_id* in *df*, I'd like to retain only the N rows with the largest values in the "probReorder" column. Also, I want N to depend on *user_id*.
In my current approach, I have a dict "lastReordNumber" whose key-value pairs are *(user_id, int)*, and I select the rows as follows:

```
predictions = []
for usr,data in df.groupby(by="user_id"):
    data = data.nlargest(lastReordNumber[usr], "probReorder")
    predictions.append(data)
df = pd.concat(predictions)
```

The problem is that this is really slow. The dataframe has around 13M rows and 200k unique *user_id*'s. Is there a faster/better approach?

**EDIT:** The previous code produces unexpected output when there are duplicate values in the *probReorder* column for a given *user_id*. Example:

```
lastReordNumber = {1:2, 2:3}
df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],"probReorder":[0.9,0.6,0.9,0.1,1,0.5,0.4],\
    "product_id":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I get the output:

```
   probReorder  product_id  user_id
0          0.9           1        1
1          0.9           3        1
2          0.9           1        1
3          0.9           3        1
4          1.0           5        2
5          0.5           6        2
6          0.4           7        2
```

which for user_id=2 is what I expect, but for user_id=1 there are duplicate rows.
My expected output is:

```
   probReorder  product_id  user_id
0          0.9           1        1
1          0.9           3        1
2          1.0           5        2
3          0.5           6        2
4          0.4           7        2
```

This can be obtained by using the simpler piece of code

```
predictions = []
for usr,data in df.groupby(by="user_id"):
    predictions.append(data.sort_values('probReorder', ascending=False).head(lastReordNumber[usr]))
predictions = pd.concat(predictions, ignore_index=True)
```

in which each column is sorted completely and then truncated. This is also reasonably efficient.
I haven't understood yet how to interpret the result of the nlargest() method, though.

Comment: What happens when you have two or more rows that equal the max?

Comment: @BobHaffner good question. It looks like nlargest is not behaving as I expected, and is duplicating some rows. Should I post the output of a test case?

Comment: I would post some additional sample data that contains another user_id.  And post your desired output too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('probReorder', ascending=False)
        .groupby('user_id', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.head([x.name]))
print (df1)
   probReorder  product_id  user_id
0          0.9           1        1
2          0.9           3        1
4          1.0           5        2
5          0.5           6        2
6          0.4           7        2
```

Another solution with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('user_id', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(lastReordNumber[x.name], 'probReorder'))
print (df1)
   probReorder  product_id  user_id
0          0.9           1        1
2          0.9           3        1
4          1.0           5        2
5          0.5           6        2
6          0.4           7        2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A few comments: drop_duplicates() does not do anything in this case as there are no duplicate (user_id, product_id) pairs. Your first solution should be equivalent to the one I provided in the edit, but it's more elegant and maybe more efficient. Your second solution does not work correctly on my machine, it produces the same "wrong" output I provided above. It could be a bug in nlargest(), I have to look it up.

Comment: As I said there are no duplicates in the ("user_id", "product_id") columns, correct me if I'm wrong, so your call to drop_duplicates does not do anything. Your two solutions are equivalent to my two solutions, but one of them does not behave as expected on my system. I consider my original question solved, but I still don't understand the issue with nlargest().

Comment: If no duplicates, simply remove drop_duplicates. And why nlargest does not work - it is hard question. I dont know. Maybe bug. For me it works nice in pandas `0.20.2`. Do you use last version of pandas? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: I have the version 0.19.2

Comment: Is posssible upgrade?